# How do I safely change things like my Prefix.pch file location, sqlitelite file name, etc. after changing app name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

After changing the name of the target and replacing the old app name at the top of every file, the only places where it still lingers are in my AppDelegate where it lists the sqlite file, and in the .xcodeprof file where it lists where the Prefix.pch file are.

However, I tried changing them and my files all turned red. How do I change it safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the path to your pch file in the build settings for your target.  The build setting is named `Prefix Header` and should be a relative path to the pch file from the root of your project.

As for the SQLite file that CoreData uses, unless you're talking about a file that's included in your application resources, you should just be able to change the file name you point your CoreData stack to while you're creating it.  Note that this will essentially have the affect of making your app create a new database file the next time it launches, so you'll have to do something more complex if you've already submitted the app and have users using the current name.

Comment: I changed Prefix Header, to newappname/... but it won't compile any more. If I then actually went and changed that folder to the new app name (in my actual folder where many of the files are stored it still had the old app name) then all the files turn red and it won't compile.

Comment: But if I put it back there's no issues.

Comment: @DougSmith Hmm, all your files turning red is probably related to the group in Xcode not pointing to the folder after you change the name of the folder in the file system.  You should go ahead and change the name of the folder in the file system and then point the Xcode group at the new folder location.  You would do this by selecting the group folder in Xcode (with all the red files in it), clicking the little folder icon in the first tab of the attributes inspector on the right (right under the Location pulldown menu), and choosing the renamed folder in the file choose dialog that comes up.

Comment: @DougSmith I know it's for flexibility, but I've always kind of hated how you can't make groups in Xcode just automatically reflect the file system.  Sometimes I feel like I spend a lot of time pointing groups at real folders.